How to Add Billing Address to PaymentSheet of Stripe?
Here is my code, which is largely based on the basic template code from Stripe:
import UIKit
import StripePaymentSheet

class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController {

    private static let backendURL = URL(string: "https://sundealit.com/stripetest")!

    private var paymentIntentClientSecret: String?

    private lazy var payButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Pay now", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemIndigo
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 12, right: 12)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.isEnabled = false
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        view.addSubview(payButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            payButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            payButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            payButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])

        self.fetchPaymentIntent()
    }

    func fetchPaymentIntent() {
        let url = Self.backendURL.appendingPathComponent("/create-payment-intent")

        let shoppingCartContent: [String: Any] = [
            "items": [
                ["id": "xl-shirt"]
            ]
        ]

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: shoppingCartContent)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data,
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String,
                let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String
            else {
                let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to decode response from server."
                self?.displayAlert(title: "Error loading page", message: message)
                return
            }

            print("Created PaymentIntent")
            print(clientSecret)
            print(publishableKey)
            self?.paymentIntentClientSecret = clientSecret
            StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey = publishableKey
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.payButton.isEnabled = true
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }

    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true)
        }
    }

    @objc
    func pay() {
        guard let paymentIntentClientSecret = self.paymentIntentClientSecret else {
            return
        }

        var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
        configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."

        let paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret,
            configuration: configuration)

        paymentSheet.present(from: self) { [weak self] (paymentResult) in
            switch paymentResult {
            case .completed:
                self?.displayAlert(title: "Payment complete!")
            case .canceled:
                print("Payment canceled!")
            case .failed(let error):
                self?.displayAlert(title: "Payment failed", message: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

}

However, in this basic template, there is no way a user can enter a shipping address, so even if they have paid money, I have no idea where to ship the product.
I looked at the documentation of Stripe here which supposedly teach me how to add the shipping address field to my mobile app in Swift: https://docs.stripe.com/elements/address-element/collect-addresses
However, the step at 4 is most confusing, where in my codes should I insert those codes in step 4, in order to get the same effect as what they showed in the image on top of that page?
In short, I need to collect user's shipping address too somehow. Thanks!

Using the AddressElement here requires the use of a UINavigationController -- you would have a button in your CheckoutViewController that when pressed triggers the UINavigationController to navigate your user to the AddressElement. That is what is being shown in step 4 of the referenced documentation.

oh! that means the address is not collected from within the payment sheet? address element is more like a separate "widget" where i can collect the address of guest? But then how do i feed in the shipping addresses collected back into the payment sheet then???

That shipping info will not appear in Payment Sheet. You either collect it and store it separately in your own database, or you could call your server and update the PaymentIntent's shipping (https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/update#update_payment_intent-shipping) for the PaymentIntent that will be used with PaymentSheet.

sorry i am still confused looking at your link https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/update. Can you write down the code and illustrate to me how exactly can i add the data (in dictionary format?) to the PaymentIntent?

since i have modified my code based on your comment, let me write a new post for consistency i guess rather than modifying the code directly from above, otherwise your answer to my question will be inconsistent
